# Add new options in drop down list depending options of other drop downlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, dropdown

I have two dropdown lists : the first contains flags of countries and the second contains languages .. I used jQuery + css + html5 to create those 2 lists.

Now I'm trying to do that: I want change options of the second list (languages) depending on which country I selected ..

For example when I spain : english flag and spanish flag appear in the list of languages

I tried that with javascript :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function checkValidOption() {
        var field = document.getElementById('countries');
        var operator = document.getElementById('operator');

        field.onchange = function() {
            fieldcheck();
        }

        fieldcheck();

        function fieldcheck() {
            if (field.value == 'br') {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = 'ad';
                opt.setAttribute('data-image', '{{ asset('
                    bundles / stageadmin / img / blank.gif ') }}');
                opt.setAttribute('data-imagecss', 'flag ad');
                opt.setAttribute('data-title', 'Andorra');
                operator.options.add(opt);

            } else if (field.value == 'au') {
                ..
                ..
            }
        }
        ..
        ..
    }
</script>
```

The country list :

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:300px;" onchange="checkValidOption();">
      <option value='br' data-image="{{ asset('bundles/stageadmin/img/blank.gif') }}" data-imagecss="flag br" data-title="Brazil"></option>
      <option value='au' data-image="{{ asset('bundles/stageadmin/img/blank.gif') }}" data-imagecss="flag au" data-title="Australia"></option>
    ..
    ..
    ..
</select >
```

this is the language list : it only contain English language at the first(flag of US appear )

```
<select id="operator" name="operator" style="width:300px;">
     <option value='us' data-image="{{ asset('bundles/stageadmin/img/blank.gif') }}" data-imagecss="flag us" data-title="United States"></option>      
</select>
```

(never mind with those 'assets' it's just because I'm using the framework symfony).

When I did that, by selecting a country nothing change in the language list ... 
I don't know what's the problem .. but when I try to just add simple options : I mean without using flag languages ... it works .. but I want it to appear with flags .

Please help me :)

Thanks

Comment: Change `operator.options.add(opt);` to: `operator.appendChild(opt);`

Comment: thank you , but it doesn't work :( does the jquery code has any affect in that ? so it's stunned in that and could not change anything

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code. on this line

```
opt.setAttribute('data-image', '{{ asset('bundles / stageadmin / img / blank.gif ') }}');
```

You have to escape single quotes or use double quotes.

```
opt.setAttribute('data-image', "{{ asset('bundles / stageadmin / img / blank.gif ') }}")
```

Also use `operator.appendChild(opt)` instead of `operator.options.add(opt)`